# AI88 textures bug on Cocos2D 1.1beta2 with TMX tile maps

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, pixel, kobold2d

Recently I migrate my project to Kobold2D 1.1 with Cocos2D 1.1beta2 inside for iPad Retina Display. But when I run my project and try to put a TMX tile map, the program hung up. The problem is CCTexture2D is call in InitWithImage and there's no Case for texture format AI88. Because of that, program goes to default and hang up.

I add to the code:

```
case kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_AI88:
    data = malloc(POTHigh * POTWide);
    info = kCGImageAlphaOnly; 
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, POTWide, POTHigh, 8, POTWide, NULL, info);
    break;
```

Is the same config as kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_A8 and now code works. I used a TMX made with Tile Editor 0.8 and uses a simple PNG not in any texture packer. The name inside TMX is fondomaze.png but in the project I must rename to fondomaze-ipad.png.

Hope you find useful. Now I can breathe relax with my project still working!

Answer (score 0):

Discover a workaround for Retina Display iPad... Must to increase malloc by 4.

```
data = malloc(POTHigh * POTWide * 4);
```

Hope helps people who want to work with RD iPad.